# Split Vector is taking too much time in mongo shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am using mongo shard distribution system. This system performs slow as the data size increases. I checked with profiler and saw split vector is taking to much time while running.

It happened after a day when one of my shard replica set went down and i had to remove that from cluster. Now i am running a single shard replica cluster. I have disabled the balancer as currently there is no second shard. Could you please help me to under stand why this process is slow.

Answer (score 1):

The splitVector commands are slow because your system is slow, it's not the cause of the slowness itself - it just happens to be running frequently and hence is showing up a lot in your logs - it is a symptom not a cause (unless you are running many, many `mongos` processes and hitting an edge case).  People often make the same mistake by misdiagnosing slow `serverStatus` commands (run every 60 seconds by MMS monitoring) as a root cause.

Usually the slowness is because your system is oversubscribed and hitting a bottleneck somewhere, but you have not provided enough information to make a guess as to what your issue is.  I would recommend looking for other evidence in the logs as well as the usual suspects (IO, CPU, Memory) to narrow down the actual root cause here.

Comment: Hi Adam I am running a mongo shard set up which has three mongos servers one is used for writing data one is used for reading data and one is used for running some aggergation scripts. I have one mongo shard which is system with 560 Ram currently i am having 1.6 TB data on this system. My question is can i put another shard in thsi system with this much data already in the system. Second my system become unresponsive for writes between 2 pm to 6 PM and if i run mongostat there are no faults. But it does not respond to the apache servers writing data in system between these hours only.